# Firebase InApp messaging crash on Android 6 and 5

Tags: android, firebase, noclassdeffounderror, firebase-in-app-messaging

My app is crashing at the opening with this error, only on Android 6 and Android 5:

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/base/CharMatcher;
        at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:69)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/base/CharMatcher;
        at com.google.common.base.Splitter.on(Splitter.java:125)
        at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.<clinit>(GrpcUtil.java:203)
        at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.<clinit>(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:84)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:48)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:27)
        at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:73)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.modules.GrpcChannelModule.providesGrpcChannel(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@19.0.3:41)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.modules.GrpcChannelModule_ProvidesGrpcChannelFactory.providesGrpcChannel(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@19.0.3:39)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.modules.GrpcChannelModule_ProvidesGrpcChannelFactory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@19.0.3:30)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.modules.GrpcChannelModule_ProvidesGrpcChannelFactory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@19.0.3:9)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.components.DaggerUniversalComponent.gRPCChannel(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@19.0.3:188)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.components.DaggerAppComponent$com_google_firebase_inappmessaging_internal_injection_components_UniversalComponent_gRPCChannel.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@19.0.3:295)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.components.DaggerAppComponent$com_google_firebase_inappmessaging_internal_injection_components_UniversalComponent_gRPCChannel.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@19.0.3:285)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.modules.GrpcClientModule_ProvidesInAppMessagingSdkServingStubFactory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@19.0.3:35)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.modules.GrpcClientModule_ProvidesInAppMessagingSdkServingStubFactory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@19.0.3:11)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.GrpcClient_Factory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@19.0.3:26)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.GrpcClient_Factory.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@19.0.3:8)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.ApiClient.getFiams(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@19.0.3:101)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.InAppMessageStreamManager.lambda$createFirebaseInAppMessageStream$16(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@19.0.3:231)
        at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.InAppMessageStreamManager$$Lambda$22.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@@19.0.3)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.M
```

This is my gradle settings:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {

    ...

    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28

    ...

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true

}
```

I am using the latest version of Firebase InApp Messaging

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.3'`

I have already found these issues, but there is not solution:

- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/630
- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1124

Does anyone have the same problem?

**UPDATE**

I solved adding Google Guava library to gradle

`implementation "com.google.guava:guava:28.2-android"`

Comment: are you using guava library in your project?

Comment: I don't use it. If you are referring to CharMatcher, I suppose it is used by some library.

Comment: I solved adding guava library in gradle

Answer (score 0):

> Use the below dependency to fix the issue

**To add a dependency using Gradle,use the following:**

```
implementation "com.google.guava:guava:28.2-android"
```

for latest guava libraries refer this [documentation](https://github.com/google/guava).